# Is there a good graphical or web-based md status or admin tool?

Tags: linux, debian, network-attached-storage, mdadm

I've got a little embedded box acting as my NAS.  It's running Debian (and yes, I know about FreeNAS and openFiler).  I've got a pair of 1TB drives doing RAID1.  mdadm is fine for me, but others in the household are less... tech savvy.  I'd like at least some kind of nice status web interface and ideally enough admin to be able to rebuild a failed drive.  Anyone know of anything like that?

Comment: I would really like to know if there is one based on the Perl Catalyst framework.

Comment: I'd love one for Plone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) is a good web interface for administration and supports mdadm.

Comment: Is it still maintained? the .debs are a coupled revs (of debian!) out of date and don't seem to be in the main debian repos anymore.

Comment: It's still maintained. The Webmin site has the newest .deb. It's the second link on the left menu and is labeled as "Debian Package".

Answer (score 4):

You can also check the "palimpsest" tool, more known under the "Disk Utility" name.
The tool has GUI (Gnome based) - GUI is very well done, self explaining and simple at the same time + all the functionality is available from GUI (including SMART).

The tool is really well made:
-> you can manage all the hard drives (SMART functionality build in) +
-> complete management of software **RAID** arrays, including creation/extension/performance checking/adding or removing disks from arrays + much more functionality - definitely it is worth the effort to try it ...

The software is available in all popular linux distributions, like the Ubuntu for instance, usually  under the "Disk Utility" name.

Schanhorst